# How to disable backspace except textbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to disable BACKSPACE button except when its in TEXT field.

I am using following code but it prevent backspace functionality include text field.. BACKSPACE should work for TEXT field only..

Please help this out...

```
$(document).on("keydown", processKeyEvents);
$(document).on("keypress", processKeyEvents);

function processKeyEvents(event) {
    // Backspace
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        // myTextBox is id of the valid textbox
        if ($("*:focus") != $("#myTextBox")) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I imported the content of your duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017224/backspace-button-need-to-disable

Answer (score 1):

Check keydown events and if `backspace` is pressed preventdefault if a textarea is not focused.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Meh/2/

```
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 8 && !$('textarea:focus').length) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
});​
```

Comment: Hi Friends, Thanks for your responses but I didnt met my requirement.

Comment: Hi Friends, Thanks for your responses but It didnt met my requirementas of now. Actually I want to disable Backspace button(keyboard button) always. but when text getting focus it should be enable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? `myTextBox` is the id of your textbox in which backspace should work.

```
$(document).on("keydown", processKeyEvents);
$(document).on("keypress", processKeyEvents);

function processKeyEvents(event) {
    // Backspace
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
        // myTextBox is id of the valid textbox
        if ($("*:focus") != $("#myTextBox")) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Friends, Thanks for your responses but It didnt met my requirementas of now. Actually I want to disable Backspace buttnon(keyboard button) always. but when text get focus should be enable.