# BACKSPACE button need to disable

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable backspace except textbox using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012024/how-to-disable-backspace-except-textbox-using-jquery)

I want to disable BACKSPACE button except when its in TEXT field.

I am using following code but it prevent backspace functionality include text field.. BACKSPACE should work for TEXT field only..

Please help this out...

```
$(document).on("keydown", processKeyEvents);
$(document).on("keypress", processKeyEvents);

function processKeyEvents(event) {
    // Backspace
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        // myTextBox is id of the valid textbox
        if ($("*:focus") != $("#myTextBox")) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare jQuery objects like that, and you only need one key event, and backspace is *not* key 9.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 8 && !$('#myTextBox').is(':focus')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why can't you compare jQuery objects like that? It works fine. Only issue is the keycode, it has to be 8 not 9.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Did it work when you tried it? That could be because of a certain browser optimization, and I don't think it's guaranteed to work well. (Even if there is some kind of wacky special case for that, `is` is better anyways.)

Comment: It worked : http://jsfiddle.net/GVpRb/1/. Maybe, you are right, it may not work in all browsers.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: You have it as `!=`. I'm saying that they'll never be equal. Look, it doesn’t even compare as equal to itself: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/GVpRb/2/

Answer (score 0):

How about using `event.target` to get the element

```
function processKeyEvents(event) {
    // Backspace
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
        // myTextBox is id of the valid textbox
        if (!$(event.target).is("#myTextBox")) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks lot musa, its working perfect what i expected......

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var elid = $(document.activeElement).hasClass('textInput');
    if (e.keyCode === 8 && !elid) {
        return false;
    };
});
```